# Installing Ubuntu 22.04 in VirtualBox says "No root file system defined"

Tags: virtualbox

My issue seems somewhat unique.Although I can find many posts about the error, it is limited to installing the OS on a hard drive.
(The computer's OS is Linux Ubuntu 22.04)
I am trying to install the OS in VirtualBox (the end goal is to use it as my front end for all internet activity).
Solutions I've read require actual partitions. They suggest creating a Linux partition and assigning it as Root. The other solution is to return to the Type page of the installer and select a partition. I am in a nascent virtual environment. I do not believe that I can do those things.
What if I load the Try Ubuntu (This works) and from there create a partition and assign it? Think that'll do it?
If you know something about installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox that might aid me in my case. Kindly share it here.
Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to specify partitions, and it's better if you don't. Use the "Try Ubuntu" if you wish, then install from there. When the installer asks where you want to install, specify the hard drive. This will be the virtual disk you created for the VM, not your *actual* storage device.

Comment: I don't understand your issue though the extreme use of bold does **not** help.  You've not said what 22.04 you're trying to install; thus we cannot know what installer you're asking about (is it `ubiquity`?  `subiquity`? or another 22.04 installer?).  If the default installation doesn't provide exactly what you want (*you didn't state if desktop/ubiquity, server/subiquity, or flavor/ubiquity|calamares*) use *manual partitioning* or *something else* to specify exactly what you want.  I've not noted anything different in virtualbox installs to hardware installs (excluding VM host setup)